# User Control code keep calling repetedly

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

> I have created a user control and registered inside asp.net page and
>   used that user control also. Everything works fine but user control
>   code executing repeatedly and thsi cycle goes on. I am not able to
>   find why this user control code keep on executing, Any help would be
>   highly appreciated.

Header.ascx code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SSBilling.UserControl.header" %>


<script language="C#" runat="Server">



public void buffer()
{
    try
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}


public string cleanupCookie(string cookie)
{
    string tmpcookie = cookie.Replace("%28", "(");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%29", ")");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%27", "'");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%2E", ".");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%3F", "?");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%2C", ",");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%5F", " ");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("%2D", "-");
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace('_', ' ');
    tmpcookie = tmpcookie.Replace("ITEMCLICK2", "itemClick2");
    return tmpcookie;


}


</script>

<%
        //************************************************************************************************
        //* 2012-06-05 HRHC
        //* * migration updated
        //************************************************************************************************
        buffer();

%>
<script language=vbscript>

sub printthis()
window.focus()
window.print()
end sub

sub backbutton()
on error resume next
<%

        Response.Write("' " + ((Request.Cookies["mID"] == null) ? String.Empty : Request.Cookies["mID"].Value) + "\r\n");
        //response.write "self.parent.document.all.tmp.tmpMenu.value = """ & cleanupCookie(request.cookies("mID")) & """" & vbcrlf
        Response.Write("top.document.all.tmp.tmpMenu.value = \"" + cleanupCookie((Request.Cookies["mID"] == null) ? String.Empty : Request.Cookies["mID"].Value) + "\"" + "\r\n");


        //response.write " if instr(1, """ & request.cookies("deptlist") & """, "","" & self.parent.document.all.tmp.currDept.value & "","") > 0 then " & vbcrlf
        Response.Write(" if instr(1, \"" + ((Request.Cookies["deptlist"] == null) ? String.Empty : Request.Cookies["deptlist"].Value) + "\", \",\" & top.document.all.tmp.currDept.value & \",\") > 0 then " + "\r\n");
        Response.Write(" if err.number <> 0 then exit sub " + "\r\n");
        Response.Write("top.go \"visible\"" + "\r\n");
        //response.write "self.parent.document.all.menuadmin.style.visibility = ""visible""" & vbcrlf
        Response.Write("else" + "\r\n");
        Response.Write("top.go \"hidden\"" + "\r\n");
        //response.write "self.parent.document.all.menuadmin.style.visibility = ""hidden""" & vbcrlf
        Response.Write(" end if " + "\r\n");



        //what?
        //Session("CurrentUserAdmin") = "Y"

%>
end sub

' 2012-04-04 HRHC
' - modified to avoid scripting error after migrated
' the following if statement only works when the 
' child and parent frames are under the same domain
'----------------------------------------------------
'If IsObject(self.parent.document.frames) Then
'    If self.parent.document.frames.length = 0 Then
'        loc = InStr(8, self.location.href, "/")
'        loc = Mid(self.location.href, loc)
'
'        location.href = "/default.asp?loc=" & loc
'    Else
'        Call backbutton
'    End If
'End If


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (top === self) {
    /*
    2012-08-18 HRHC
    - no in the trinity frameset (both zone and new app), call the default page.
    this will no longer be used after app migrated
    */
    var loc = "";

    top.location = "/default.aspx?loc=" + loc;
} 
else {
    /*
    - in the frameset, do nothing
    */
}
</script>

<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/include/content.css">

<%
//response.write "hello from header.inc<br />"
%>
```

> 

Registerd in asp.net page like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="header" 
    Src="~/UserControl/header.ascx" %>
```

And called the header.ascx like this:

```
<uc:header id="ucHeader" runat="server"></uc:header>
```

> Thank You!

Comment: share some code and tell which platform you are using.

Comment: Please check, i have updated the Question, Visual studio IDE and it is a web app in asp.net using C#